# generating exception classes via decorators in python

Tags: python

While coding, I have to do this frequently;

```
class MyClassException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, _message):
        self.message = _message

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        raise MyClassException("What's up?")
```

It'd be nice to be able to have my Exception classes via a decorator call, since all those dummy classes all inherited from Exception have nothing unique but name. The following would be great for instance;

```
 @generic_exception_class
 class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        raise MyClassException("What's up?")
```

Since there's no way to make MyClassException present until the decorator is called it'd give me <strike>syntax</strike> name error no matter what. Is there a way to do this in python in any similar way?

Comment: The decorator is called as soon as the class is instantiated. Where's the problem?

Comment: syntax error caused by MyClassException not being defined beforehand

Comment: 1) That would be a name error, not a syntax error. 2) Python won't care that it doesn't exist until `__init__()` is actually called.

Comment: You can simplify this with: `class MyClassException: pass` and later `raise MyClassException("What's up?")`

Comment: @Ignacio - Ooops, that was meant to be `class MyClassException(Exception): pass`

Comment: @Ignacio - My bad, that'd be a name error not a syntax error, but it still seems to care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility.  Note that the exception class will be a member of the decorated class, it is not at global scope.

```
# The decorator
def class_with_exception(cls):
    def init(self, _message=''):
        self.message = _message
    excname = 'ClsException'
    excclass = type(excname, (Exception,), {'__init__': init})
    setattr(cls, excname, excclass)
    return cls

# example usage
@class_with_exception
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        raise MyClass.ClsException('my message')

# raises and catches exception
try:
    MyClass()
except MyClass.ClsException:
    print 'catching exception'
```

Comment: Seems like a workable idea :) Thanks. If we don't get to see anything better, I can accept this reply.